# testing java ee 6 with junit 3

Tags: java-ee-6, junit4, junit3

I have a short question: Can I test java ee 6 with junit 3, or do I have to use JUnit 4?

Answer (score 1):

No, JUnit version 3.8 and earlier supports Java up to version 1.4.

Source: http://www.methodsandtools.com/tools/tools.php?junit